# Need to create an array formula where the target ranges are not in fixed locations

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently I am using the following formula in successive rows on a sheet named Data

```
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($Q$2=DMS!$I$1:$I$99999,ROW(DMS!$I$1:$I$99999)-ROW(DMS!$I$1)+1),1),"")}
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($Q$2=DMS!$I$1:$I$99999,ROW(DMS!$I$1:$I$99999)-ROW(DMS!$I$1)+1),2),"")}
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($Q$2=DMS!$I$1:$I$99999,ROW(DMS!$I$1:$I$99999)-ROW(DMS!$I$1)+1),3),"")}
```

...

For a total of 30 rows to determine the first 30 rows within Sheet DMS column I that match the value in my sheet 'Data' cell Q2.

I am trying to find a way to either recreate the above arrays, or an alternate solution to using the arrays, when the searched range is no longer going to be a fixed location. Essentially what was in column I could be in column J tomorrow and H the next day and back to I for the next 3 days. I will be able to tell where it is by the column header, so I do have one static point of reference, even if it is not in a fixed column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula. It looks for a column with the text "TheKey" in the first row of columns A to Z and will then perform the match on the values in the found column.

In Excel 365, you can just hit enter, in earlier versions, you need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($Q$2=INDEX(dms!$A$1:$Z$9999,1,MATCH("TheKey",dms!$A$1:$Z$1,0)):INDEX(dms!$A$1:$Z$9999,9999,MATCH("TheKey",dms!$A$1:$Z$1,0)),ROW($A$1:$A$9999)),ROW(A1)),"")
```

In Excel 365, you can avoid the duplication of the Match function by applying the new Let() function and re-using the result. Like this:

```
=LET(myColumn,MATCH("TheKey",dms!$A$1:$Z$1,0),IFERROR(SMALL(IF($Q$2=INDEX(dms!$A$1:$Z$9999,1,myColumn):INDEX(dms!$A$1:$Z$9999,9999,myColumn),ROW($A$1:$A$9999)),ROW(A1)),""))
```

I removed the `-ROW(DMS!$I$1)+1` because that does not do anything, really. Just subtracts 1 and then adds 1 again.

I also replaced the hard-coded number for subsequent rows (1, 2, 3, etc) with `Row(A1)`, which will evaluate to 1 in the first row of the formula and when copied down will turn into 2, 3, 4, etc without having to adjust the formula for each row.

Comment: I did not know about the LET function. I'm still used to old Excel versions. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine several advanced functions. First of all, you need to locate that header, because it's your only static point.

[image]

You can locate your static header using:

```
=CELL("address";INDEX(DMS!$A$1:$M$1;;MATCH("STATIC HEADER";DMS!$A$1:$M$1;0)))
```

In this case, it will return this text: `[Libro1]DMS!$I$1`

It's the complete path to cell.

Now you need to combine that string, with OFFSET to get a reference to that column and get like 99999 rows of data. ISsue here is OFFSET does not work on different worksheets from active one, so you need to combine it with INDIRECT first to get a reference to range in sheet `DMS`:

> **[INDIRECT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)**
>
> **[OFFSET function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66)**

So then a formula like next one will return a reference of 1 column and 99999 cells where your static header is:

```
OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address";INDEX(DMS!$A$1:$M$1;;MATCH("STATIC HEADER";DMS!$A$1:$M$1;0))));0;0;99999;1)
```

So now you can combine all of these into a really huge formula:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($Q$2=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address";INDEX(DMS!$A$1:$M$1;;MATCH("STATIC HEADER";DMS!$A$1:$M$1;0))));0;0;99999;1);ROW(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address";INDEX(DMS!$A$1:$M$1;;MATCH("STATIC HEADER";DMS!$A$1:$M$1;0))));0;0;99999;1)));ROW()-5);"")
```

Notice I've deleted the `ROW(DMS!$I$1)+1` because that's always equal to 0, so not needed. I addedd in SMALL function the part `ROW()-5)` so I can drag down (i'm testing in row 6 and dragging down. No need of those 1, 2, 3 you input manually). Adapt this part to your needs.

[image]

Notice that if `STATIC HEADER` is in a different column, the formula still works.

[image]

I've uploaded a file do my Gdrive in case you want to see how it works, because copying so many functions can be crazy.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Y6mQ_hiu1TKLXhTUgvq8tN67eHQKtVb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Both OFFSET() and INDIRECT() are volatile and will cause slowness. They should be avoided and in most cases are not required to do the job.